# Question about S.A. Choudam's proof of Erdos-Gallai theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

In case (3) of S.A. Choudam's proof for the Erdos-Gallai theorem, the author claims "If $k + 2\geq p$, then $t = p - 1$." How does the latter follow from the former in the context of the proof?

The author also claims that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} d_{i} = k^{2}-k + d_{k+1}$$

This seems to imply that $d_{k+1} = k$, but it's not clear to me why that would be the case

Here's a link to the [proof](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/FCA8B7DC763D3D504C68E3A5FDD8DE45/S0004972700002872a.pdf/simple_proof_of_the_erdosgallai_theorem_on_graph_sequences.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Assumption: The condition for all terms of the degree sequences has been omitted, as the graph is a complete graph, and solving it involves substituting the first position of difference as the second last term. This is just an assumption as we subtract 1 from the next term and would like to make it the last term which we subtract it from.

First we will look at the underlying assumption in the proof for case 3
$k \le t-1$ & $d_k = k$. There is atleast one more term in the degree sequence (otherwise it is the same case as the assumption) so $p \ge t+1$. Since $k+2 \le t+1$ and it is given that $k+2 \ge p$ $\Longrightarrow$ $p = t+1$.
Also for the second part of the question recall that $d_t$ was the first position of difference such that $d_{t+1} \lt d_t$ and $d_{k+1}$ is $d_t$ so it will have the same value as any other $d_i$ $(i \lt k)$ which is $k \Longrightarrow$ $d_{k+1}$ is also $k$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).